# Update web.config in Chef Windows web deployment

Tags: windows, iis, deployment, web-config, chef-infra

I am learning and trying to implement chef for IIS web deployment in windows. I need some help regarding update web.config file.

I got from internet we have to create erb template file with web.config having place holder ( `=node['cookbook']['variable']`), so that we could replace that place holder with environment specific attribute values in run time.

How could I sync my erb file with latest build web.config? If I take and update the file from CI server when CI process is running how could I add place holders?

I have lots of file (5 to 6) to update the environment specific values, so I thought of editing config file directly once deployed in server instead of replacing with erb file for easy maintenance. Will it be could idea? Will it break idempotency? Which one is good method in terms of easy maintenance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The template file data lives inside the cookbook, so you manage it alongside the recipe code and other cookbook files. Generally when you move something to be managed by Chef, you'll grab the current file contents from a server manually and paste it into a template file. Then edit it to add the `<%= @name %>` value placeholder or other more complex stuff like `each` loops. After that point, all changes to the files have to be done through updating the Chef cookbook or Chef will undo the changes the next time it runs.